# Is it possible to process messages from multiple WMQ queues using Spring Boot with annotations?

Tags: java, spring, ibm-mq, spring-jms

Straight forward question, is this possible to do using Spring Boot and doing my configuration with annotations using a `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` with an external properties file (where the queue definition resides)? If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back on this, this was an oversight on my part. Of course this is possible. Using annotations, specifically the `@JmsListener` I can connect to however many queues I want. After the initial setup of the `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory`, all I have to do is put in my listener class:

```
@JmsListener(id = "q1", destination = "queue1")
    public void processOrder(String message) {. . .}
@JmsListener(id = "q2", destination = "queue2")
    public void processOrder(String message) {. . .}
:
:
@JmsListener(id = "qN", destination = "queueN")
    public void processOrder(String message) {. . .}
```

and for pre-Java7 you can make use of `@JmsListeners`, but I didn't delve too far into that, but from what I understand it allows you to attach multiple destinations onto a listener.